# Aho-Corasick algorithm to scan through a list of strings

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/243254/finding-min-and-max-values-of-an-iterable-on-the-fly) about finding min and max values of an iterable.
Aho-Corasick algorithm was suggested to solve the problem. Below is my solution with the use of [ahocorapy library](https://github.com/abusix/ahocorapy/blob/master/README.md).

Short re-cap of the problem:

> You are given 2 arrays (`genes` and `health`), one of
>   which have a 'gene' name, and the other - 'gene' weight (aka
>   *health*). You then given a bunch of strings, each containing values `m` and `n`, which denote the start and end of the slice to be applied
>   to the `genes` and `health` arrays, and the 'gene'-string, for which
>   we need to determine healthiness. Then we need to return health-values
>   for the most and the least healthy strings.

I think there might be something off with the code, but not sure what. It works quite fine for small testcases, giving more or less same timing as previous versions of the solution showed, but when it comes to large testcases, my PC basically hangs.

Example of a small testcase:

```
genes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'd', 'b']
health = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
gene1 = "1 5 caaab" (result = 19 = max) 
gene2 = "0 4 xyz" (result = 0 = min) 
gene3 = "2 4 bcdybc" (result = 11)
```

Large testcase (2 lists 100K elements each; testcase 41K+ elements): [txt in my dropbox (2,80 MB)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9l566nl7ucj69ra/DNAHealth%20HR%20problem%20Large%20testcase1.txt?dl=0) (too large for pastebin)

**So, I have 2 questions: 1) What is wrong with my code, how can I impore its performace
2) How do I apply the Aho-Corasick without turning to any non-standard library (because, most likely, it cannot be installed on HackerRank server)**

```
def geneshealth(genes, health, testcase):
    from ahocorapy.keywordtree import KeywordTree
    import math

    min_weight = math.inf
    max_weight = -math.inf

    for case in testcase:
        #construct the keyword tree from appropriately sliced "genes" list
        kwtree = KeywordTree(case_insensitive=True)
        fl, ceil, g = case.split()
        for i in genes[int(fl):int(ceil)+1]:
            kwtree.add(i)
        kwtree.finalize()
        #search the testcase list for matches
        result = list(kwtree.search_all(g))

        hea = 0
        for gn, _ in result:
            for idx, val in enumerate(genes):
                if val == gn:
                    hea += health[idx]

        if hea < min_weight:
            min_weight = hea
        if hea > max_weight:
            max_weight = hea
    return(min_weight, max_weight)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is slow because:

1. It builds a new keyword tree for each test case. Just build it once, using all the genes.
2. It builds a list of all the matching keywords. `KeywordTree.search_all()` is a generator, just loop over it directly. And,
3. It loops over the list of genes to find the gene index, so that it can find the health.
   Instead, build a dict with the genes as keys and an (index, health) tuple for the value.

Something like this (untested):

```
import math
from collections import defaultdict
from ahocorapy.keywordtree import KeywordTree


def geneshealth(genes, health, testcases):

    # build the kwtree using all the genes 
    kwtree = KeywordTree(case_insensitive=True)
    for gene in genes:
        kwtree.add(gene)
    kwtree.finalize()

    # build a dict that maps a gene to a list of (index, health) tuples
    index_and_health = defaultdict(list)
    for gene, data in zip(genes, enumerate(health)):
        index_and_health[gene].append(data)

    min_dna_health = math.inf
    max_dna_health = -math.inf

    for case in testcases:
        start, end, dna = case.split()
        start = int(start)
        end = int(end)

        dna_health = 0

        # search the dna for any genes in the kwtree
        # note: we don't care where the gene is in the dna
        for gene, _ in kwtree.search_all(dna):

            for gene_index, gene_health in index_and_health[gene]:

                # only genes that are within the testcase limits
                # contribute dna_health
                if start <= gene_index <= end:
                    dna_health += gene_health

        # keep the min/max weight
        if dna_health < min_dna_health:
            min_dna_health = dna_health

        if dna_health > max_dna_health:
            max_dna_health = dna_health

    return(min_dna_health, max_dna_health)
```

Comment: Will have to test it yet, but all the suggestions seem useful, so thank you. I noticed you put imports outside the function - does that effect the performance much?

Comment: It is common practice to put `import` statements at the top of the file.  It doesn't affect run time performance of the code.  There are some cases in which it makes sense, or is necessary, to put the imports in a function.

Comment: I tried out your code. Firstly, `testcases` is a collection of strings, so I replaced `for start, end, dna in testcases:` with `testcases_lst = []

    for i in testcases:
        x,y,z = i.split()
        testcases_lst.append((int(x), int(y), z))

    for start, end, dna in testcases_lst:`
Please, advice if there's a more efficient way to do that, although I tried it out separately, and it's quite fast

Comment: Secondly, there is another issue: consider 1st gene in the light testcase above, `1 5 caab`. Now, in the `genes` array there are 2 `b` genes, one at index 1, another at index 5. Both should be counted, but only the second was, giving the result of 17 instead of 19. I'm not sure how to account for that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, @RootTwo, can you explain how the line `gene_index, gene_health = index_and_health[gene]` works?

Comment: @DenisShvetsov I revised the code for the 1st two questions.  In the old code `index_and_health[gene]`  looks up `gene` in the dict and returned a 2-item tuple.  The assignment uses [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) to assign the item in the tuple to `gene_index` and `gene_health`.  In the revised code, the dict lookup returns a list of tuples.  The for-loop `for gene_index, gene_health in index_and_health[gene]:`  gets the an item in the list, unpacks the values, and executes the loop body for each item in the list.

Comment: I tested your code, it works perfectly. Timing for the large testcase is about 10 seconds as opposed to 164 seconds for best of the earlier solutions. Too bad HackerRank can't handle non-standard libraries

Comment: @DenisShvetsov you can write your own algorithm in about [50 lines of python](http://algo.pw/algo/64/python).